# GL_INVALID_OPERATION when calling gluLookAt

Tags: macos, opengl, glulookat

I've been getting into OpenGL on OS X lately (tl;dr: I'm a OpenGL noob) and got some code working that draws a cube. However, I don't see any of the faces (besides the front) since my view isn't translated. I try to use the `gluLookAt` function to do this translation, but I get an `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error. This is how I do my rendering:

```
// Activate and lock context
[_glView.openGLContext makeCurrentContext];
CGLLockContext(_glView.openGLContext.CGLContextObj);

// Update camera position
gluLookAt(0, 2.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
gl_GetError();

// Update viewport and render
glViewport(0, 0, _glView.frame.size.width, _glView.frame.size.height);
[_renderer doRender:time];

// Unlock and flush context
CGLUnlockContext(_glView.openGLContext.CGLContextObj);
[_glView.openGLContext flushBuffer];
```

This code works when I comment out the `gluLookAt` call, and from what I can gather from the docs, this error is caused by executing `gluLookAt` between `glBegin` and `glEnd`. I don't know if where these are getting called, as I do not call those myself, and wrapping the call to `gluLookAt` in `glBegin` and `glEnd` does not solve the issue.

If it makes a difference, I'm using OpenGL 3.2 Core Profile.

Comment: Someone looking at the opengl tag must be going around and -1-ing almost every question without comment. This is really bugging me.

Comment: @thokra i just upvote it again.. if you think a question is bad, explain why, no excuses.

Comment: @AntonD: So you downvoted, then upvoted again because you couldn't give an explanation? I'm a little confused.

Comment: The only downside to doing that is that an upvote has a greater magnitude than down. So the initial downvote causes an individual to lose 2 rep, but then the upvote to restore the nominal score to 0 earns the author 5 rep. Overall the individual earns +3 rep on a question that appears at first glance to be neutral. +3's not a lot, but upvoting to restore the number to 0 does not actually restore status quo.

Comment: @thokra ofc not, i'm not english so sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way, `gluLookAt (...)` (and GLU in general) is not a part of OpenGL. This is why you will not find documentation directly explaining the cause of this error.

The only reason it generates `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is because behind the scenes it does this: `glMultMatrixf (...)` (which ***was*** a part of GL once upon a time). That is invalid in a core profile context, because there is no matrix stack anymore; anything that was *deprecated* in GL 3.0 or 3.1 is *removed* from GL 3.2 (core profile).

If you need `gluLookAt` / matrix stack functionality on OS X, [GLKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKit_Collection/_index.html) provides a suitable collection of replacement utilities. Alternatively, you can use a much more portable (C++ based) library called [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html) if you compile using Objective C++.

---

Now, the far simpler solution here is not to use a core profile context. If you are using things like `gluLookAt (...)` you are likely learning legacy OpenGL. You need a context that supports deprecated parts of OpenGL, and on OS X this means you need a 2.1 context.

Comment: +1: Also, [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html) is a very good library substituting some GLU functions, including `glmLookAt()`.

Comment: I considered mentioning that, but I was not sure if it would work in an Objective C application.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that is was objective C. Can you interface with C++-code in ObjC?

Comment: Yeah, the lines that make no sense to most C programmers like this: `[_renderer doRender:time];` are a dead giveaway ;) I just checked and GLM can be used if the software is compiled as "Objective C++".

Comment: Thanks — I figured the majority of docs on the Internet seem to use legacy OpenGL, and I didn't read the part of the docs that states 3.2 Core removes the deprecated stuff. I'll look into GLM and see how it works!